# Print Subsequences of given length "k" from an Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, subsequence

Getting Runtime error for this code :-

```
import numpy as np
   def combination(inp,n,k,ans):
      if len(ans)==k:
        print(*ans)
      else:
        if len(inp)>0:
          b=[]
          b=ans.append(inp[0])
          combination(inp[1:],n,k,b)
          combination(inp[1:],n,k,ans)
n=int(input())
a=list(map(int,input().split()))
a=np.array(a)
k=int(input())
ans=[]
combination(a,n,k,ans)
```

But why it is showing run Time error for this ?

Comment: you need a breking condition otherwise it will loop for ever and ever. Use a return and clarify what do you except from your program, i.e. what kinf of return?

Comment: Please give us an exemple of the input you're trying with. Moreover, `inp` is not defined

Comment: The test case is :-
Input
3
1 2 3
2

Comment: Please provide the expected output and input. Also, paste the full error trace - on what line are you seeing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, variable reassignments, and other side effects.

We can write fixed-length combinations `choosek` using [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. if size `k` is zero, yield the empty combination
2. (inductive) `k` is greater than zero. if the iterable `it` is empty, stop iteration
3. (inductive) `k` is greater than zero and the iterable `it` has at least one element. for each `comb` of the sub-problem `choosek(it[1:], k - 1)`, prepend the first element of `it` to the resulting `comb` **and** yield each result of the sub-problem `choosek(it[1:], k)`

```py
def choosek(it, k):
  if k == 0:
    yield ()                               #1
  elif not it:
    return                                 #2
  else:
    for comb in choosek(it[1:], k - 1):    #3
      yield (it[0], *comb)
    yield from choosek(it[1:], k)
```

Notice the `print` side effect is moved outside of the function so the caller can do whatever they choose with the resulting combinations -

```py
for comb in choosek("", 2):
  print("".join(comb))
```